# Determining if the clicked cell is an all-day event in fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the [fullCalendar plugin](http://fullcalendar.io) and I am trying to figure out how can I determine if the clicked cell is an all-day. I already checked the docs but I can't find it there.

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
$('.calender').fullCalendar({
  allDaySlot: true,
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    // click event trigged
    // but how can I determine if its an all-day?
  } 
});
```

Comment: You can not access it directly, because a day can have multiple events, and these events can be allDay and not allDay during the same day. What if a day has a allDay Event and another non allDay event? Should be the clicked day in an all-day event or not? You can see what I mean in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hBAfSR?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `eventClick`.
The first parameter of the `eventClick` function callback is the event object.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    // click event trigged
    if(calEvent.allDay) {
        // all day
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

"date holds a Moment for the clicked day. If an all-day area has been clicked, the moment will be ambiguously-timed." - [FullCallendar Doc](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/)

Try this:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    // click event trigged
    if (!date.hasTime()) {

        alert("should be all-day");

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your input, but I need to determine if the clicked cell is an all-day, not in event of calendar.

Comment: I'm sorry @kRiZ, but that doesn't work in that way. You can reproduce here http://plnkr.co/edit/hBAfSR?p=preview

Comment: Hi Mario, Thanks that should do!

Answer (score 1):

The below code works, which was found on fullcalendar github page.

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  if (!date.hastTime()) {
    console.log("It's an all day slot");
  } else {
    console.log("Not an all day");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of the accepted answer, except with a not-equal operator in the `if` statement.

Comment: Though it looks duplicate, I hope it'll help any new users to understand where actually the logic is present and how it works.